# Master Data Services

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, master-data-services, master-data-management, mds

I'm a SQL Server developer learning MDS. I loaded some entities via staging tables and via Excel add-in.

I'm trying to update members in an entity in MDS via the staging table. I can successfully add new members, but any attribute updates to existing members  aren't populated to the entity view. The import process runs successfully with no errors.

I've tried `ImportType = 0` and 2, neither works. When I set to 1, as expected I get an error. I also tried to update the code value using the `NewCode` column and that also does not get updated.

I've set up staging data with an SSIS package, and also with direct T-SQL `INSERT INTO` statement.

I am using almost the same T-SQL `INSERT` statement for a test entity which I created to load a new member, and then to modify attributes for the new member in a second batch.

Do you have any ideas why the updates would be ignored, or suggestions for things I can try?

Answer (score 0):

Look at  your batch in the staging table to see if an errors occurred.  If the "ImportStatus_ID" = 2 then the record failed to import.  You can see the reason for failure by querying the view that shows reasons for the import failures.  The view will be named "stg.viw_EntityName_MemberErrorDetails.

Here is a Microsoft link for reference:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff486990(v=sql.110).aspx

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested above Member error details view describe the error
Make sure that you are checking below points when updating in MDS
1) Put code column in your INSERT statement
2) Include all columns of staging table in INSERT query when using 
importType = 2 (Otherwise all column will be updated as NULL)

Answer (score 0):

You should insert the data into staging table with ImportType as 0 or 2 along with the batchtag and then run the staging stored procedure to load the data from staging table to entity table. SP will compare the data from staging table with the data in entity table based on Code value and update the data in entity table.

Answer (score 0):

While you can update importstatus_id in the stg.leaf table. 
     update stg.C_Leaf
     set
     ImportStatus_ID = 0
While I think it will force the data to be ready for staging and load to mdm entity.

Answer (score 0):

Using Import type =0 shall help u update the new attributes untill the updated new attribute has NoT Null Data. If it is so then Update shall fail. Recheck the data in entity.

If that doesn't work. Please try to refresh the cache in Model and try to get the entiry details again.

Learn more about import types in MDS from below link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/master-data-services/leaf-member-staging-table-master-data-services?view=sql-server-2017

Hope this helps.